# MSVS 2017: Pointer null check not behaving as it should

Tags: c, pointers, null, visual-studio-2017

I have written the following "Hello world!"-level code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double *Bptr = NULL;
    printf("Bptr's current value is: %p\n", Bptr);
    double Barray = 1.02;
    Bptr = &Barray;
    if (Bptr == NULL); {printf("Bptr is still a null pointer: %p\n", Bptr); };
    if (!Bptr); {printf("Bptr is still a null pointer (check 2): %p\n", Bptr); };
    printf("The address of Bptr is: %p\n", Bptr);
    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run the above using Visual Studio 2017, this yields the following curious output:

```
Bptr's current value is: 00000000
Bptr is still a null pointer: 00B3FD58
Bptr is still a null pointer (check 2): 00B3FD58
The address of Bptr is: 00B3FD58
```

Which, unsurprisingly, is not what I intended. This is the first time I encountered this problem. It is also the first time that I started a MSVS project as an 'empty project', in stead of a Windows console/desktop application, so I suspect it may have something to do with that. Does anybody have any suggestions as to what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Where did that last line of output come from? There's no code for that

Comment: There is a semicolon after if condition.

Comment: Also `if (Bptr == NULL);` is an empty statement after the condition. The `printf` is unconditional

Comment: @kmchmk :  There is no code for any of this output - the text in the "output" differs from that in the code.  Looks like it was manually typed rather then a direct copy & paste - either that or it is output form different code.  It is academic however, since problem is simply the placement of a null-statement and unconditional blocks.

Comment: What is `B`? There is no `B` in your code. Please post the actual code that you are compiling.

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon after if statement, remove it and it will work. :)

Comment: Of course that solved the problem. I cannot believe I missed something that silly. Thank you

Comment: After _both_ if statements in fact.

Comment: @FlorisSA ; Perhaps your ill-advised code layout makes such things harder to spot.  Always placing the conditional block open-brace on a new line will make the stray semi-colon easier to spot.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, Clifford. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You are using **semicolon** after **if** statement. That's why, printf statement is always executed despite of condition. And no need to put semicolon after curly braces, it does nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    double *Bptr = NULL;
    printf("Bptr's current value is: %p\n", Bptr);
    double Barray = 1.02;
    Bptr = &Barray;
    if (Bptr == NULL) {printf("Bptr is still a null pointer: %p\n", Bptr); }
    if (!Bptr) {printf("Bptr is still a null pointer (check 2): %p\n", Bptr); }
    printf("The address of Bptr is: %p\n", Bptr);
    return 0;
}
```